# connect localhost from another machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile

Is there anyway i can navigate to a website i develop on my computer from a smartphone connected to the same network?
the site is running on localhost, can I make a bridge or something like that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can if you use you're IP directly as the website's name.For example in TOMCAT all the sites are localhost:port/Project_name/filename.html

So if you would use `"http://your_ip:port/Project_name/filename.html"`, it should work.

As a note, the firewall may stop this from working.

Comment: If you also want to connect from outside, and know anything about routers, you can access your website from outside by typing in the router IP (your internet IP). For that you will need to know about NAT routing.

Comment: Absolutely.If you want to acces the website from within your broadcast domain, then you can use the local IP granted by the router.Usually 192.168.x.xyz. If you are outsite the domain then use the ip given to your router.

Comment: Yes I understand, but i still can get any access to the site, I've disabled my firewall and when I navigate to the site i get a http 400 error. :\

Comment: you deplyed your application in which server? IIS ?

Comment: try checking if the router(if you have one) doesn't block acces

Answer (score 1):

As long as your site is available to the network, just use the name of your PC.

So if you were developing on `http://localhost:12345` connect using `http://muzE-PC:12345` (assuming `muzE-PC` was the name of your computer)

Comment: Well thats what I thought and tried before, but it looks like something is preventing me from getting to the site.
Maybe the firewall? how can I fix it?
Edit: Disabled firewall and I get HTTP Error 400...

Answer (score 1):

instead of localhost use, ip address.

Make sure that website is not blocked by [windows firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall).

[ipconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig) can be used to determine ip address.

On remote system, localhost will refer to that remote system (not the system on which web site is running).